# How to dropdown to meta box and save data in meta data in db wp?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I create a custom post type of name courses. For this custom post type create a dynamic dropdown meta box data is shown in dropdown but not save in db.Please check my code where i am doing wrong to save data .My meta box is showing up fine, but the data I enter is not saving. I.e. when I click 'update' on the post the meta box reverts back to my placeholder text.

```
 if ( ! function_exists('add_courses') ) {
    // Register Custom Post Type
    function add_courses() {
    $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Courses', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Course', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Courses', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Courses', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Course Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Course Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Course:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Courses', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Courses', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Courses list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Courses list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Courses list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Course', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Add Courses', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 
 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array('post_tag'),
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'wpt_add_faculty_metaboxes',
    );
    register_post_type( 'course_type', $args );
    // register taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('courses', 'course_type', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Course Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'course-type' )));
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'add_courses', 0 );
    function wpt_add_faculty_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
    'wpt_faculty_member',
    'Faculty',
    'wpt_faculty_member',
    'course_type',
    'side',
    'default'
    );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpt_add_faculty_metaboxes' );
    function wpt_faculty_member() {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'event_fields' );
    $faculty_roles = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $args = array(
    'role'    => 'faculty',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
    );
    $faculties = get_users( $args );
    echo '
    <select name="faculty_role" id="faculty_role">
      <option value="">Select Faculty...
      </option>';
      foreach ( $faculties as $faculty ) :
      echo '
      <option value="' . $faculty->ID . '">' . $faculty->user_login . '
      </option>';
      endforeach;
      echo '
    </select>';
    }
    /**
    * Save the metabox data
    */
    add_action( 'save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 1, 2 );
    function wpt_save_events_meta( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Return if the user doesn't have edit permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
    return $post_id;
    }
    // Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['faculty_role'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['event_fields'], basename(__FILE__) ) ) {
    return $post_id;
    }
    // Now that we're authenticated, time to save the data.
    // This sanitizes the data from the field and saves it into an array $events_meta.
    $events_meta['faculty_role'] = esc_textarea( $_POST['faculty_role'] ); 
    // Cycle through the $events_meta array.
    // Note, in this example we just have one item, but this is helpful if you have multiple.
    foreach ( $events_meta as $key => $value ) :
    // Don't store custom data twice
    if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
    return;
    }
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
    // If the custom field already has a value, update it.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
    } else {
    // If the custom field doesn't have a value, add it.
    add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
    }
    if ( ! $value ) {
    // Delete the meta key if there's no value
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
    }
    endforeach;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

New solution, as of WP 3.7: `save_post_{$post_type}`

```
add_action( 'save_post_my_post_type', 'wpse63478_save' );
function wpse63478_save() {
    //save stuff
 }
```

Comment: values are not display in dropdown after update or add

Comment: Try it like this ---- `$faculties = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'faculty' ] ] );`